# initramfs after upgrade Linux kernel ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade, kernel, initramfs

After upgrading to Linux 5.15.0-60-generic from Linux 5.15.0-58-0 generic, It is not booting. It keeps hanging at initramfs. I tried the following

1. exit turns nothing
2. blkid turns nothing
3. dmsetup ls turns 'No devices found'

I tried to repair the boot using a live USB repairboot but failed to boot from the USB. It won't reboot. It keeps going to grub and there are two Linux kernels with their recovery options but all of them end as shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsMhW.jpg)
Please, can you throw me some advice to resolve this problem or on how to back up my files.

Details of my laptop:
My dell xps 13 7390 2-1 model ( I wiped the windows and installed ubuntu 20.04. It was working for two years until the above problems started two days ago.)

Thank you in advance

Comment: it  looks like your disk is dead if you didn't do anything to it manually. If it fails to boot from a USB, it's even worse.

Comment: I did some pre-boot test, and it shows the hard disk is health, actually all the parts are in good shape. I am just lost on how to boot from USB in the dell xps 13 7390 2-1 model. @Pilot6 do you have any idead about this machine? please throw some advise.